# Saving as .xlsx in different directory in vba

Tags: excel, vba, save, save-as

I am trying to use the `SaveAs` method to save a .csv document as a .xls document.  However, when I try and designate the folder, it fails.

For example, it will save to some default directory (my documents, which is not where I am ready from) here:

```
Sub csv()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="directory/tmp.csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="test.xlxs", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

But this fails:

```
Sub csv()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="directory/tmp.csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="otherdirectory/test.xlxs", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Is there a different way to specify the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FileFormat:=xlCSV`

This works for me.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test.csv", FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False
```

Whenever in doubt, record a macro :)

The `FileFormat` Constant is `xlCSV`. Either you can type `FileFormat:=xlCSV` or you can use it's actual value which is 6

**EDIT**

I see that you have edited the question :) Let me go through it again :)

> > > Is there a different way to specify the directory? Thanks,

What is the exact path that you are specifying? I used `Filename:="C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"` and it works perfectly.

Comment: reverse the slashes and try again :) `"C:\Users\mikefree\Desktop\test.xlsx"`

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.  Sorry for that, I've used forward slashes before without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Siddarth suggests and specify the directory by writing out the entire path.
Alternatively if you wanted to have a user be able to change the directory the file is stored in when saving you could use:

ChDrive (filePath)
ChDir (filePath)

Where filepath would be a starting directory for use with Application.GetSaveAsFilename. The user could then type in the name of the file or change directories if need be.